# Virtual Box MySQL Server VM constantly timing out

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, virtualbox

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL server hosted in a VirtualBox VM with the following configuration file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3311
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3311
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address           = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 16M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 200
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 200
table_cache            = 64
thread_concurrency     = 10
# 
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 8M
query_cache_size        = 32M
# 
# * Logging and Replication
# 
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
# 
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
# 
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
innodb_use_sys_malloc =  0


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

# 
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
# 
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

The error I get is :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on host

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and PDO driver.
Is this happening because being hosted in a VirtualBox VM?

Comment: Can you ping the IP address you are using in your connection string?

Comment: @RobertMoskal yes I can ping the IP address. I can establish connection and it works great but sometimes it gives me timeout a few times in a row. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment the bind-address argument to allow for connections outside of the VM.

```
bind-address           = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I've done what you suggest and I'll try if this solved the problem!

Comment: You did not say in your question that the connection is successful and then times out. Plus I don't think that you can get an external connection without un-commenting that directive.

Comment: Un-commenting that line solved the issue. Thanks Robert Moskal!